# Storing data inside a ruby gem, where / how to write files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working on a Ruby parser, that fetches data from different API sources, and compile this data into a clear read-to-use JSON file.

For my use case, i need to store the data i'm initially fetching from the different sources as i don't want to fetch them each time I use the code.

For now i'm writing the JSON i'm receiving from the API sources locally into different JSON files stored in a data folder where my ruby script is. Then i read those files again, parse them and generate my new formatted JSON file that i'm gonna use later in a Rails app.

For that matter i want to create a Gem from this ruby script, which i'm currently working on. Nevertheless i'm not sure to fully understand how and where i should store that data (the one i'm fetching and the one i'm generating).

For now i have tried to simply keep the code as is and simply try to write the file like so:

```
URI.open("path/to/where/i/wanna/store/file.json", "wb") do |file|
   file << URI.open(fetched_data_url).read
end
```

But wherever i try to write the data i get a :

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen path/to/where/i/wanna/store/file.json
```

Which in a way does not surprise me that much as i expected it to work in different ways in the context of a Gem. But i'm still missing something here about how to handle this. I'm not sure to fully understand how that all works, especially when you use paths in a gem that will ultimately be used in a rails project.

So several questions here:
Whenever you use a path to write a file inside a Gem, is that path relative to the gem or to the project that will ultimately use that Gem? (and consequently will the file be written inside the project that uses the Gem?)

In that precise use case here, what should i do about it? Where and how do i store my data so that i can use it later? knowing that i need to store it as a JSON file and that for now any attempt of writing a file ends up with an error.

Any input on what i'm misunderstanding here would be much appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: This sounds like a X&Y problem. Are you sure you actually need to save it a file and that you can't just read the response into memory or stream the response directly into whatever process you're doing with it? If not can you use `Tempfile` to create a tempory file? There is no simple cross platform solution to where to write files without configuration. You need a folder which is writeable by the user running the rails server or job and for security reasons that user generally should have as few priviledges as possible.

Comment: You may be right, I wanted to store that data because i didn't wanted to make those API calls and parsing jobs each time I'm trying to access the data. But maybe I should return that JSON response and let the Rails app using the gem write the data on it's own if needed. That would solve my problem

Comment: If you're writing a gem thats intended as part of Rails app you can use its built in low-level caching. That way you don't have to worry about the nitty gritty as a gem author. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Comment: The hard thing is really as always comming up with a cache invalidation stategy which will work for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever you use a path to write a file inside a Gem, is that path relative to the gem or to the project that will ultimately use that Gem?

There is nothing special about using file paths whether the code is part of a Gem or not.

`path/to/where/i/wanna/store/file.json` is a *relative path*, which means it is looked up relative to the *current working directory* of the user who started the script. That's nothing special about Gems, that's not even anything to do with Ruby. That is just how file paths *work*. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, absolute paths are not.

> Where and how do i store my data so that i can use it later?

This depends largely on the Operating System Environment. Different OS Environments have different conventions where to store what kind of files. E.g. your files look like they fit the definition of a *cache* and Windows has a dedicated folder for caches, as does macOS, as do Linux distributions that follow the Linux Standard Base, as do Desktop Environments that follow the Free Desktop Standards, as does Android, as does iOS, …

For example, the Free Desktop Group has the [*XDG Base Directory* Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/), which defines directories for application state, application data, application cache, and many other things for XDG-compliant environments. Microsoft has similar specifications for Windows. The LSB [has something to say as well](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s05.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jörg, and for clarifying what I misunderstood here. 

Sounds like saving the data through the Gem would then generate a lot of complexity for what i want to achieve. Thought back at it and most likely i'm gonna keep the "storing data" part out of the gem. The gem would then only return the needed data and the storing part would belong to the app using the Gem.